# Current Password Having to Enter Hash?

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

On my changepassword form, problem is when I go to change the password, it is not letting me enter my current password, instead it requires the md5 hashed password. Once entered however, it is sent hashed so that part is good.

```
<?php
    include 'core/login.php'; 
    include 'core/init.php';    
    include 'includes/head.php';    
    if(count($_POST)>0) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *from users WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"]) {
    mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users set `password`='" .md5(md5($_POST['password'])) . "' WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
    $message = "Password Changed";
    } else $errormessage = "Current Password is not correct";
    }
?>
```

Form is

```
<form name="frmChange" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return validatePassword()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Change Password*</label>  
                        <input type="text" name="currentPassword" class="form-control input-md" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>New Password*</label>  
                        <input type="text" name="newPassword" class="form-control input-md" />
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirm Password*</label>  
                        <input type="text" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control input-md" />
                    </div>                          
                    <br />                  
                    <div class="text-center"> 
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />        
                    </div>                                      
                </form>
```

and JS is...

```
<script>
function validatePassword() {
var currentPassword,newPassword,confirmPassword,output = true;

currentPassword = document.frmChange.currentPassword;
newPassword = document.frmChange.newPassword;
confirmPassword = document.frmChange.confirmPassword;

if(!currentPassword.value) {
currentPassword.focus();
document.getElementById("currentPassword").innerHTML = "required";
output = false;
}
else if(!newPassword.value) {
newPassword.focus();
document.getElementById("newPassword").innerHTML = "required";
output = false;
}
else if(!confirmPassword.value) {
confirmPassword.focus();
document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "required";
output = false;
}
if(newPassword.value != confirmPassword.value) {
newPassword.value="";
confirmPassword.value="";
newPassword.focus();
document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "not same";
output = false;
}   
return output;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are doing:

1. Taking user input
2. Getting hashed password from database
3. Comparing the hashed password to the user input
4. Hashing the user input
5. Inserting the user input into the database

You need to hash the password before you do the comparison. i.e.

1. Taking user input
2. Getting hashed password from database
3. Hashing the user input
4. Comparing the hashed password from the database to hashed password from the user input
5. Inserting the user input into the database

That said, you are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Answer (score 0):

hashing a password with md5 is NOT secure. Use the hash(..) function instead and sha256 or sha512. Using a salt would be also a good idea.

php-script:
In the if you should hash the currentpassword too. Assuming that the password in the db is also hashed.

Comment: What would that look like comapred to my code? Not sure how to do this together